# Fluids - vector identity confusion

Tags: vector-analysis, fluid-dynamics

Trying to prove Kelvin's Circulation Theorem, but struggling to see why the following equality holds:

> $$\textbf{u} \cdot (d\textbf{l}\cdot \nabla)\textbf{u} = d\textbf{l} \cdot \nabla \left(\frac{1}{2} u^2 \right)$$

I don't really have much idea where to start. I can take that gradient on the RHS, but that is of a scalar function and I'm not sure how I'll be able to get the vector $\textbf{u}$ out in the way that looks anything like how it should on the LHS...

Any hints would be appreciated (don't mind a solution either)

Edit: added picture of $d\mathbf{l}$ representation from notes. [image]

Comment: What do $\mathbf l$ and $d\mathbf l$ signify? Also, I take it that $u=||\mathbf u||$?

Comment: We define it in the notes as $d\mathbf{l} = \mathbf{x_1} - \mathbf{x_2}$, so a material line element. Added picture to text...

Comment: There is something missing in that equation. It is not dimensionally consistent, the LHS has unity of $m^4/s^3$ and the RHS $m^2/s^2$.

Comment: I took it from here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/372611/148271. After 'so'...

Comment: Well, you have a $\mathbf{u}$ instead of a $\nabla$ in the LHS.

Comment: AH yes, typo in the text, thanks, but I am still confused...

Comment: The scalar product is commutative, therefore you can forget the $d\mathbf{l}$ for a while, do you see that? Well, you need to show that $\nabla (\mathbf{u}\cdot \mathbf{u})/2 = \mathbf{u} \cdot \nabla \mathbf{u}$.

Comment: Oh that is trivial, just the product rule, thank you. Just needed commutativity!! Post that as an answer - I will accept :)

Comment: Yes, this equation is not dimensionally consistent; for $[\text{LHS}]=m^4/s^3$ and $[\text{RHS}]=m^3/s^3.$ Check your notes; isn't there some operator on the left?

Comment: @rafa11111 $(u\cdot \nabla) u = u_i\partial_i u_j$, not so sure about commutativity

Comment: @CalvinKhor That's because the nabla operator isn't actually a vector. It's more subtle then mere commutativity:
$$
\mathbf{u} \cdot (d\mathbf{l}\cdot \nabla)\mathbf{u} = u_i \mathbf{e}_i \cdot (dl_j \mathbf{e}_j\cdot \partial_k \mathbf{e}_k u_l \mathbf{e}_l) = $$$$u_i \mathbf{e}_i\cdot(dl_j \partial_j u_l \mathbf{e}_l) = u_i dl_j \partial_j u_i
$$

Comment: I know, I'm just trying to understand how you used the commutativity of the scalar product @rafa11111

Comment: @CalvinKhor do you think it’s wrong? I have an exam today so need to be sure I’m not claiming the wrong things 

Comment: @PhysicsMathsLove well the answer below is definitely correct

Comment: @CalvinKhor I used the commutativity to change the order between $d\mathbf{l}$ and $\mathbf{u}$ in the RHS, i.e., $\mathbf{u} \cdot (d\mathbf{l} \cdot \nabla) \mathbf{u} = (\mathbf{u} \cdot d\mathbf{l}) \cdot \nabla \mathbf{u} = d\mathbf{l} \cdot (\mathbf{u}\cdot \nabla \mathbf{u})$, so that OP's identity could reduce to $\mathbf{u}\cdot \nabla \mathbf{u} = \nabla (\|\mathbf{u}\|^2/2)$.

Comment: @rafa11111 but (say $d=dl$ to make typing easier) in LHS its $u_i d_j \partial_j u_i$ so $d$ is never dotted with a $u$, so how do you get a $u\cdot d$ term? also $u\cdot d$ would be a scalar as well so i dont know how to dot with the matrix $\nabla u$ to get a scalar. I think it should be something horrid like $(u\otimes d) : \nabla u$ (just a guess, I didn't check)

Comment: @rafa11111 also, $(u\cdot \nabla)u = u_i\partial_i u_j = \nabla\cdot(u\otimes u) ≠ \nabla(\|u\|^2/2)=u_i\partial_j u_i$, I think?

Comment: @CalvinKhor You are right, what I did is messed.

Comment: thanks for the confirmation, sorry to be the bearer of bad news! @rafa11111

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
d\textbf{l} \cdot \nabla \left(\frac{1}{2} u^2 \right)
&\;=\; \sum_{\mu\, \nu} dl_{\mu} \, \frac{\partial}{\partial x_{\mu}} \, \frac{1}{2} u_{\nu}u_{\nu}\\
&\;=\; \sum_{\mu\, \nu} dl_{\mu} \, u_{\nu}\, \frac{\partial}{\partial x_{\mu}} u_{\nu}\\
&\;=\; \sum_{\mu\, \nu} u_{\nu} \, dl_{\mu} \, \frac{\partial}{\partial x_{\mu}} u_{\nu}\\
&\;=\; \mathbf{u} \cdot \bigl[
\left(d\mathbf{l}\cdot \mathbf{\nabla}\right) \mathbf{u}
\bigr]
\end{align}